# Getting the value from a input form with dynamic value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built some forms dynamically:

```
[] [] = row[1][0], row[1][1] each with the class "main_class"
```

There is the potential to have hundreds of these fields.

I want to check the input value when a user enters it into the form. For instance to ensure that the values are numeric and not text. Or to ensure a specific higher and lower value are adhered to.

This is what I have thus far:

```
$('.main_class').on('input', function() {
     var n = $('.main-balls').val();
});
```

How do you get a value of the specific input field?

Comment: Use `$(this)` and read manuals.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.main_class').on('input', function() {
     var n = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did as per the suggestion from u_mulder.